# Multiview Vrs Multiple aspx pages - which one is better..?? (regarding speed..)

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hii..
I am using a Multiview for a application. Each aspx page contains Multiview.

A single multiview contains atleast 5 to 6 views. (so less no. of aspx pages). When user clicks any button such as say "Edit View" (where user can edit his entries), a diffrent view is displayed. So user feels that he is redirected to another page. So a single aspx page has lot of controls, lot of code - a lil bit heavy page.

Will it affect loading time? is it better to use different aspx pages?

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use different pages for different views. The number of aspx pages doesn't affect the performance, but managing each view on its own page is easier for maintenance.

You may use Multiview for some sort of wizard, but it is better to not use it to just reduce the number of aspx pages in the app.

Answer (score 1):

Alex is right. Even if your views aren't displayed the controls contained in those views are persisted in the __VIEWSTATE. if you take a look at the source of your pages in your browser theres proably going to be a few Kb's of VIEWSTATE.

A colleague once built a page that had 380Kb of VIEWSTATE. That will affect performance!

Answer (score 1):

Multiviews can work great in minimalist settings, but don't do like I did early on and attempt to build the equivalent to a 15 page medical form all in one ASPX page using the MultiView. If you are building short and sweet panes your performance will not suffer as much, but you will eventually cross the threshold and your performance will go into the gutter.